# How can I make a button link to another page?

Tags: html, button

This is my HTML so far

```html
<button type="button" formaction="contact.html">Get In Touch!</button>
```

For some reason when I click on the button in a browser it doesn't take me to the contact.html page. All the pages that came up in google helped me learn new button attributes, but I couldn't figure out how to make the page redirect on click.

Comment: This has been answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: Why not use a normal link instead? Format it via CSS to look as “button-y” as you want.

Comment: @CBroe DOH! Don't know why I didn't just think of that haha. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `formaction` is only supported for `type="submit"` (See: [HTML button tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp))

Answer (score 4):

If you are using bootstrap, you can use this to do it for you:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Link Button</a>
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp

Comment: I just want to add that if you are using Google Analytics to monitor your site, a normal hyperlink with <A href=""></A> would be an easier solution to track clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```html
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='contact.htm';" value="Contact" />
```

The better way is that you surround the above code with `<form></form>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try these methods:

```html
<!-- Using window.location.href = 'URL' -->
<button onclick='window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com"'>
  Click Me
</button>

<!-- Using window.location.replace('URL') -->
<button onclick='window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com")'>
  Click Me
</button>

<!-- Using window.location = 'URL' -->
<button onclick='window.location = "https://stackoverflow.com"'>
  Click Me
</button>

<!-- Using window.open('URL') -->
<button onclick='window.open("https://stackoverflow.com","_self","","")'>
  Click Me
</button>

<!-- Using window.location.assign('URL') -->
<button onclick='window.location.assign("http://www.stackoverflow.com")'>
  Click Me
</button>

<!-- Using HTML form -->
<form action='https://stackoverflow.com' method='get'>
  <input type='submit' value='Click Me'/>
</form>

<!-- Using html anchor tag -->
<a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>
  <button>Click Me</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```html
<a href="contact.html"><button type="button">Get In Touch!</button></a>
```